# Profile Completeness reminder to the user

Tags: 6, hooks

Hi i need to send an mail reminder to the user whoever not been completed the profile information. Is there any module available  for this? or how do i do this?

Can we do this using rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at [Profile Complete Percent](http://drupal.org/project/pcp) (for core Profile module) [Content Complete](http://drupal.org/project/content_complete) (if using [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile)).

If you are using Content Profile, here is an article to assist setting up with [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules): [Measure node completion in Drupal, part 3](http://nuvole.org/blog/2010/apr/12/measure-node-completion-in-drupal-part-3).  I'm sure you could probably get a Rules workflow going with core Profile module as well.

Comment: Thanks Laxman13. `Content Complete` worked for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal 7 (for the benefit of those coming to this at a later date) you can use the [Field Complete](http://drupal.org/project/fc) module. It has Views and Rules support as well as additional Field module integration. (For the sake of transparency, I wrote it.)

Answer (score 0):

I would build a module that checks the db tables to see if they dont have the default values in them.

If the default value exists, then setup mailing on cron to send reminder mail. just be careful cause if you run cron 10 times in a day that could get very irritating for you users ;)